# prevent wordpress from counting total posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i would like to display 20 posts ONLY in my frontpage so i created a function to alter the query like this :

```
if( is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('communique-presse', 'info-algerie'));
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '20');
    }
```

it is working but what i want is to prevent wordpress from calculating the number of pages when generating pagination.

I tried $query->set('paged',1), $query->set('paged',-1) etc... but wordpress is still calculating the number of pages.

I'd like to prevent wordpress from counting the total posts to optimise my site, since i have 50 000 + posts and i think that by disabling total posts counting will optimize the query, so wordpress query only the furst 20 posts without traversing all my 50 000 posts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need code to say how many posts you want on your frontpage, this is a setting in the admin dashboard, here: /wp-admin/options-reading.php

And WordPress likely won't iterate over all of your posts to count them and will just call the `count()` function on the database, so there should be nothing to optimize here.

Comment: I'd like to show 20 posts ONLY in homepage, not in category page where the number of posts is 10, do you think that count() function doesn't eat ressources ? i think that count() will look at least ids of my +50 000 pots which is yet too much, isn't it ?

Comment: I guess the performance of count will depend on the indexes, anyway, if what you really want to do is change the home page and only the home page you should write a template in your theme that do exactly what you want. Since the pagination is part of your theme just don't put pagination in that template and you won't have any count done. Once you have your template create a page using that template then set that page as your home page.